# Lambda download and forward PDF (PDF proxy)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i'm wondering what am i doing wrong with this lambda function.

Goal:

Send http options to fetch an PDF and forward it to consumer from Lambda service.

Current code:

```js
"use strict";
const http = require("http");

function getPDF(options, event) {
   console.log(options);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let body = "";
    let statusCode = 0;
    let headers = { };
    
    http
      .request(options, (res) => {
        statusCode = res.statusCode;
        const headersFromReq = res.headers || {};

        res.on("data", (chunk) => (body += chunk));

        res.on("end", function () {
          console.log( statusCode, headers, body);
          resolve({ 
            body: Buffer.from(body).toString(),
            statusCode, 
          headers: {
            ...headersFromReq, 
            //'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
            //'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.pdf'
          }
        });
      })
      .on("error", reject)
      .end();
  });
});
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const response = await getPDF(event.options, event);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
      headers: {}
    };
  }
};
```

Whatever i've tried, it either times out or does not result in the actually needed response of Base64 encoded PDF.

Params for testing would look something like this:

```js
{
  "options": {
    "hostname": "www.africau.edu",
    "port": 80,
    "path": "images/default/sample.pdf",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36",
      "Accept": "application/pdf",
      "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
    }
  }
}
```

Current logs -

```
Function Logs
START RequestId: 8d6be86c-788d-4f49-8305-8caf377cd32e Version: $LATEST
2021-09-28T09:01:21.507Z    8d6be86c-788d-4f49-8305-8caf377cd32e    INFO    {
  hostname: 'www.africau.edu',
  port: 80,
  path: 'images/default/sample.pdf',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36',
    Accept: 'application/pdf',
    'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
  }
}
END RequestId: 8d6be86c-788d-4f49-8305-8caf377cd32e
REPORT RequestId: 8d6be86c-788d-4f49-8305-8caf377cd32e  Duration: 11011.54 ms   Billed Duration: 11000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 54 MB  Init Duration: 152.43 ms    
2021-09-28T09:01:32.494Z 8d6be86c-788d-4f49-8305-8caf377cd32e Task timed out after 11.01 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach has an underlying conceptual problem - it may take time to execute. The time that you don't have when you run things in lambda. Your lambda "technically" has the maximum of 15 minutes to finish the execution (although you explicitly have to configure it. I think by default it's 10s), but if you trigger it from AWS API Gateway, that goes down to 30 seconds and this is not a limit you can configure. It's the total max. Moreover your lambda response cannot be larger than 6MB and it is normally supposed to be JSON, so you would have to convert your file to Base64, but again, if you serve that file via api gateway even that limit goes down once again... What you're trying just cannot be done reliably with lambda in this way. There is a different way however that would actually be recommended by AWS.

1. You send a request to API Gateway that triggers a lambda
2. Lambda looks up if the requested file already exists in S3

- If it doesn't exist:

  - The lambda downloads a file and puts it into S3. Note that you can now set up S3 bucket policy so that file stays in S3 only for certain amount of time. You probably don't want to keep it there forever, but it's nice to keep it cached for a while in case the user tries to re-download your PDF. This way they will be able to get the response much faster
  - The lambda then generates a pre-signed S3 URL to the freshly downloaded file (a special URL that you can request from S3 that will be valid for another few minutes only) and returns it in the response
- If it already exists:

  - the lambda just generates the pre-signed S3 URL and returns it in the response

3. Your client (UI application I presume) has to generate a consecutive request to the pre-signed url received in the response (so it talks directly to S3). This way, even if your user has slow internet connection and they need 20 minutes to download the file, you don't get any timeouts... well you will still get some if the file is really large and the lambda cannot download it quickly enough, but that would require a longer discussion. In this case I'm assuming your file is under 15MB.

Comment: Thanks for the much-needed answer. Think I'll pivot to some other solution outside AWS eco system.

Comment: that's also an option, but even if you moved away from AWS solutions, you still don't want to do it the way you attempted. You shouldn't need to download the file before serving it. You can just pipe the data stream between the request and the response so that your endpoint really acts as a proxy downloading and uploading the data in the same time without using more than a few bytes of memory at a time, instead of loading the whole 10MB file into memory before you pass it to the consumer